# What does removeAllViews() do with child views?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have the following hierarchy in my layout:

```
ScrollView
    RadioGroup
        RelativeLayout
            RadioButton
            ImageView
        RelativeLayout
            RadioButton
            ImageView
            ...
```

Now the point is, that it looks fine in the XML editor where `RadioButtons` and `ImageViews` have default values (placeholders) defined, but when I launch an activity and call `removeAllViews()` on the `RadioGroup`, all `ImageViews` disappear. What's interesting, all buttons get new values, only `ImageViews` are not updated anyhow (setting new source images gives no results).

So, my question is: does `removeAllViews()` erase the child views completely (like they never existed in a layout XML file) or just removes some values leaving the views' arguments to be defined (like setting new source image or new button description)?

Answer (score 5):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()), `removeAllViews()`:

> Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup.

Calling this method will set all the childs view to `null`, so it will remove the child views from itself, and this child becomes **not valid** (or not considered as child), but not like it never existed in XML file.

This is [removeAllViews() code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.removeAllViews%28%29):

```
public void removeAllViews() {
     removeAllViewsInLayout();
     requestLayout();
     invalidate();
}
```

As you can see in [removeAllViewsInLayout()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout%28%29) method, it set the child value to null:

`children[i] = null;`

Comment: Okay, that explains a bit more. What would be the reverse sequence to have the children views available and usable then?

Comment: I don't think there is a reverse for `removeAllViews();`, you can use `addView();` to add again your views to the ViewGroup.